# IIS Url Rewrite or MVC Routing to show a sub domain in a browser address bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, url-rewriting

My MVC 3 site is deployed on IIS7 and the "page-in-question" is accessible at `mysite.com/fileUpload/`

When a user navigates to `mysite.com/fileUpload/`, I want his browser address bar to show `file.mysite.com/` after the page has loaded.

Is it possible with IIS7 Url Rewrite or MVC routines?

P.S. `file.mysite.com` is not a real site that is accessible via sub-domain - it is just a name I want the user to see.

There seems to be a lot of similar questions, but 80% of them discuss the opposite requirement, and other 20% are somewhat different.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx) which illustrates how a custom route could be used to map subdomains to routes.